# Django Broken Link After Deployment

Tags: python, django

After deploying my web app django starts sending me mails of broken links. I've been trying hard since yesterday to solve the problem but no success.

The mail I got is;

```
Referrer: http://tesst.com/listing/
Requested URL: /favicon.ico
User agent: Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/7.5.31657/28.3030; U; en) Presto/2.8.119         Version/11.10
 IP address: 000.00.0.00 #just used this 0 to represent IP address of the user.
```

in my template at the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="webmaster" content="test@gmail.com" />
    <link href= "{{ MEDIA_URL }}/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/css/style.css"/>
    <title> {% block title %} {% endblock %} </title> 
   </head>
```

UPDATE: This is the views

```
      def lispy(request):
          cripys=Wriby.objects.all()
          for crip in cripys:
              print crip.id
              return render_to_response('partners.html',{'cripys':cripys,'crip':crip},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
         else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid')
```

How can I get get rid of this problem?

Comment: You want to get rid of emails or 404 on your site?

Comment: Can you post view code for /listing/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your favicon isn't available. Check to see what the following renders on your page:

`{{ MEDIA_URL }}/favicon.ico`

Plug that into your browser. You will likely not get anything in which case the path to the icon is wrong.

Comment: it return an image after inserting that link in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS in your settings.py. The docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#send-broken-link-emails